# Has someone successfully compiled freetype with MinGW/MSYS?

Tags: cygwin, mingw, gnu-make, freetype, cygpath

I am unsucessful trying to compile freetype with MinGW/MSYS

Here's what I do:

From `cmd.exe` I switch in to `MSYS`:

```
C:\temp\freetype-2.3.5-1\src\freetype\2.3.5\freetype-2.3.5>bash
```

And then call the `configure` script

```
bash-3.1$ ./configure

FreeType build system -- automatic system detection

The following settings are used:

  platform                    unix
  compiler                    cc
  configuration directory     ./builds/unix
  configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk

If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove the file
`config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file for help.

Otherwise, simply type `make' again to build the library,
or `make refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).

cd builds/unix; ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32

[------ Deleted some 121 lines because they seem irrelevant for the problem ------]

config.status: creating ftconfig.h
make: Nothing to be done for `unix'.
```

After configuring freetype, I want to use `make` to compile the sources:

```
bash-3.1$ make
/bin/sh: cygpath: command not found
config.mk:36: /builds/freetype.mk: No such file or directory
config.mk:57: /builds/unix/install.mk: No such file or directory
builds/toplevel.mk:158: /builds/modules.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/builds/modules.mk'.  Stop.
```

The problem seems to be *cygpath*, which is strange, because I haven't installed cygwin.

Since the compile instructions mandate *gnu make*, I verified this:

```
bash-3.1$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys
```

What do I do wrong?

**Edit**: There is also `Makefile.mingw` in the directory. Trying to start the compile process with `make -f Makefile.mingw` doesn't finish either, returning the message `¨make: *** No rule to make target 'MFSED', needed by 'all'.  Stop.`.

**Update** Ok, I have done some detective investigations into the matter, and it seems that the problem is *precisly* because I haven't installed CygWin. I have this assumption because `cygpath` is a CygWin utility ([See here](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath)) that converts unix-paths to windows-paths and vice versa.

Now, a `¨find . -type f -exec grep -l cygpath {} \;` finds several locations where `cygpath` is used:

- ./builds/unix/aclocal.m4
- ./builds/unix/configure
- ./builds/unix/unix-def.in
- ./builds/unix/unix-def.mk
- ./patches/freetype-2.3.4.diff
- ./patches/freetype-2.3.5/builds/unix/unix-def.mk
- ./patches/freetype-2.3.5.diff

and I think I'd have to change something in one or more of these locations to fix the build. Right? I am still hoping that someone with more knowledge about the entire ./configure-build process can give me a hint on the issue.

**Update II**: From *rubenvb's* answer, I figured I could try `./configure --build=i686-pc-mingw32` and *then* remove the line reading

```
TOP_DIR := $(shell cd $(TOP_DIR); cygpath -m `pwd`)
```

in `builds/unix/unix-def.mk` and *then* change the line reading

```
RCTOOL_COMPILE = RCTOOL
```

to

```
RCTOOL_COMPILE = $(RCTOOL)
```

in `./builds/freetype.mk` and also copying http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/rctool.sh.txt to `c:\mingw\bin` (since there were strange errors because of the missing `rctool.sh`) and *then* start the compile process with `make`.

Now, the compilation of the source files seemed to (at least partially) complete at last, although I have gotten  *many* warnings like

```
./src/base/ftcalc.c:75:3: warning: 'FT_RoundFix' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
```

But the linker is unable to link the *.o files because there are many undefined references like

```
C:\temp\freetype-2.3.5-1\src\freetype\2.3.5\freetype-2.3.5/src/base/ftinit.c:89: undefined reference to `_imp__FT_Add_Module'
```

I guess the compile-warnings are not unrelated to the linker errors.

So, what now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, compiling unix/linux software on Windows can go two ways:

1. Use the existing configure scripts from MSYS or Cygwin.
2. Use a supplied mingw makefile from cmd.exe (the windows shell).

You tried the first (but I think not hard enough), and did the second one wrong:

1. Try passing `--host=i686-pc-mingw32` to configure. The script is telling you it detects a unix build, which is horribly wrong and as you can see, does not work.
2. You can also use `mingw32-make` directly from cmd.exe to use the makefile.mingw you have found. It should work fine.

Try to locate a README or INSTALL file in the main source directory. It should tell you what to do and probably has a windows specific section.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. Unfortunatly, neither option changed anyting, both still produce the same error related to the missing `cygpath`. I found a README (actually called *INSTALL.UNIX* and *UPGRADE.UNIX*, both of which are explicitly stated for MinGW/MSYS use) and the tell me to do basically what I already did. I don't argue that I didn't try hard enough (although I spent 4-5 hours already), but is not the point of the entire ./configure thing not to have to worry about different plattforms?

Comment: Well, cygpath should not be needed in an msys environment. Are you sure using the mingw makefile from the windows console (cmd.exe) using mingw32-make doesn't work?

Comment: When I open a cmd.exe and cd into `C:\temp\freetype-2.3.5-1\src\freetype\2.3.5\freetype-2.3.5` and do a `mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.mingw`, after printing lots of lines it finally prints `mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target `MFSED', needed by `all'.  Stop.`

Comment: @René: then there's something wrong with their makefile. But your directory structure is pretty deep (probably has nothing to do with your problem though...)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Something must heve gone wrong with my unzipping the sources. I have downloaded another source-zip-file, and it is currently building the library. Seems as though it's going to work this time.

Comment: As time passes by and problems change: I stumbled upon this answer, because the dependency chain of msys2-freetype2 stopped at ole32, which was not part of msys2. Now it is even easier to compile freetype. download the source, open mingw32 /mingw64 shell, `./configure`, `make -j SOME_NUMBER`, done.